# How do I send a piece of HTML in Outlook Web Access?

Tags: html, outlook-on-the-web

How do you send a HTML email in Outlook Web Access?

I have the HTML written but if I just copy and paste it, it will just send as plain text. I have no idea how to do it. Is it possible?

[image: Screen Shot of new Email window]

Email:

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <style> body {
     font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",
          Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
     text-align:justify;
     color: #CFB52B;
     background:#000000;
     background-attachment:scroll }</style>
    </head>

   <body>
<table border= "0" align="center" style=" width:500px;">
    <tr style="height:550px; width:200px;">

        <td bstyle="width:550px" style="text-align:top; vertical-align:top;">
            <div align="center">
                    <img src="EngLOGO.jpg" alt="IMAGE LOADING" height="350px" border="0">
            </div>

            <p style="text-align:justify;">Hi All<br /><br /></p>
            <p style="text-align:justify; line-height:26px">

            Thanks<br />BOB<br />

            <br /></p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this Serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/q/172634/53979)?

Comment: I don't know but I'd be surprised if OWA lets you use the email editor window as an HTML editing window. I'd guess that it lets you do WSYWIG editing which is either serialized to plain text or serialized to HTML. To do otherwise would put OWA at a huge risk for XSS attacks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/536275/

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the html into a file  (test.html), view it with a browser (so that the HTML renders), copy the contents and then paste them into the compose window?

I haven't tried this, and don't know if there may be any issues with Outlook-web styles vs the style-declaration in the HTML.

But logically it's the first approach to test.